# create a new column in a data.table from group by multiple columns

Tags: r, data.table, plyr

I'm working on a data.table that includes X and Y columns and I want to create a new column Z which is the number of all records with the same value of (X, Y).

I know the syntax when working with a data.frame:

```
ddply(df,.(X,Y),nrow)
```

I tested different syntaxes I found on this forum but they didn't work:

```
dt[, Z := lapply(.SD,nrow), by="X,Y"] # or   
dt[, `:=`(Z = lapply(.SD,nrow)), by="X,Y"]
```

I precise X and Y are numeric.

Answer (score 4):

Starting from

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(X = c(1, 1, 2), Y = c(1, 1, 2))
```

The appropriate syntax is

```
dt[, Z := .N, by = c("X","Y")]
```

or

```
dt[, Z := .N, by = .(X,Y)]
```

Comment: I get the Error   \`[.data.table\`(dt, , \`:=\`(Z, .N),  : 
  Type of RHS ('integer') must match LHS ('list'). To check and coerce would impact performance too much for the fastest cases. Either change the type of the target column, or coerce the RHS of := yourself (e.g. by using 1L instead of 1)error message

Comment: You already have a column named Z, with a different data type. If you don't need it try to remove Z first using `dt[, Z := NULL]`.