# data.table to aggregate key column by count

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, aggregate

I have a large dataset (>1 million rows) with 10 columns. I would like to aggregate the dataset by the first column, and add a new column with count. I tried using aggregate but it's taking too much time. After some research it seems data.table would make things go faster. Here's what I have now:

```
person <- person[, .(count= .N), by=ID]
```

I think I might be missing an argument here. ID is the first column from my person data table. Currently it only outputs 2 column, one for the ID and one for the count, but I want to include all the other columns as well.

Edit:
Also tried this:

```
person2 <- person[person[, .(count= .N), by=ID]$ID]
```

All my data becomes "NA".

Data:

```
ID Age Air Test Class Condition Result Inq Manu Trans
234551 25 1 02 C 2 1 2 1
234551 26 - - C 2 1 1 5
421331 45 1 - C 1 0 1 4
```

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46134936/create-a-new-column-in-a-data-table-from-group-by-multiple-columns)

Comment: and not correct `data.table` syntax; `person[, count := .N, by = ID]`

Comment: that one relates to a count based on 2 columns, I'm trying to group by just 1 column

Comment: If you want it for only one column then write only one column in `by=` and it works. Aggregation and manual join back will be a lot slower than using `:=`, I guess.

Comment: okay tried count := .N, it added a column but didnt group the key column. I expect the number of rows to be reduced

Comment: Ok, I guess we need an example. `person[, c(.(.N), lapply(.SD, first)), by=ID, .SDcols=other_cols]` might work, but I'm making assumptions about the data here. Alternately, your way could work, if it's like `person[.(person[, .(count= .N), by=ID]$ID), on=.(ID), mult="first"]` perhaps.

Comment: @Frank added some data. I think I understand my problem now. Really would need 2 steps, first to get count based on the 1st column, then only keep the first occurrence of the ID if that make sense. I think I know how to do it now. Thanks